# Application does not enter into application didfinishlaunchingwith option after user push home button

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

I am developing an app which makes use of the `UILocalNotification` to do the scheduling task. There is a class which handles the scheduling task and its function is called from both `applicationdidfinishwithlaunchingoption` and `didReceiveLocalNotification` to handle the task for both active and not active state. I set the key of "Application does not run in background" to YES in my plist file.

My user schedule the task and then click on homebutton. When they see a banner of `UILOcalNotification` and they click on it, neither `didfinishlaunchingwithoption` is fired nor `didReceiveLocalNotification` is fired. I tried setting "Application does not run in background" to No and they check for the handing the task and it works good in that mode however I do not want to be in this mode cause I heard Apple reject some app due to background running if they do not do any relevant task like VOIP or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `didfinishlaunchingwithoption` method should fired but you can't see it in debug mode. I have an Alarm app and i also set `Application does not run in background` to yes , i faced this situation a lot.

So, my suggestion is edit the Scheme and switch the launch option to `wait for app to launch manually`. and debug to see if it's fired.[image]

Comment: How would i do that if I change the scheme and set it to Wait for appname.app to be launched manually... is simply shows waiting for appname to launch and it does not show the icon in my simulator as well.

Comment: Yes, and when your tap the app icon or the notification bar, you Xcode will enter debug model.

Comment: No sir...I can not see the app icon on my simulator and clicking on notification does not work as well!!!!

Comment: You should set launch option to automatically at first time. and I wonder if you can not see the app icon , how can you receive local notification?

Comment: I see the app icon if I set the option to Automatic launch and I schedule task and I get notification. I don not see app icon neither able to open the app if I set the option to "Wait for appname.app to be launched manually.". I do that after I deleted the app and reinstall it with this option. So not able to schedule and not getting notification.

Comment: Hmm, you can try this : 1.set the option to Automatic and schedule the  notification. 2.press home button to quit app. 3. set the option to wait for appname.app to be launched manually and run. 4. when you receive the notification, tap app icon or notification.

Comment: my bad luck its still not entering into didfinishlaunchingwithoption however what I just felt one type of scheduling of task just worked but others are not. Will apple reject my app if I set the option of Application does not run in background to YES. I am not doing any background task though, just handling the UILocalNotification.

Comment: apple won't reject you . but maybe you can post some code about your local notification and let more people help you.

Comment: Thanx for your help johnMa... I tried some other format and it worked out for me. I will post the code as soon as possible so that other user can know about it. See yah.